# Danger of using "Too Broad" as a catch-all default for closing offtopic posts?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I've realized that I've gotten into the habit of just using "Too Broad" as my default close reason when a post is offtopic for reasons not covered by other categories, and I don't have the time/will to enter in a custom close message.

For example, I just saw a question asking for the contact information for a software company. I mindlessly voted to close it as too broad, then actually sat there and thought about it. There aren't really any other appropriate options other than a custom reason. In retrospect, the closest reason actually seemed to be "requesting offsite resource", but the question itself is objective, while that's a subjective close reason, so that didn't seem appropriate.

For cases where I'm unwilling/unable (I'm getting off a bus, etc) to enter in a custom close reason, what's better?

- Close as Too Broad, or whatever the closest reason is.
- Skip it and leave close votes to people willing/able to put the time in. This runs the risk of bad questions not getting enough votes to be closed though, and getting washed away by new questions.

What should I do to help the most/cause the least harm?

---

I don't think this necessarily is answered by [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip). I'm not talking about using queues, and the linked answers seems to be debating irrelevant points.

Comment: I'm always a little surprised when I go looking for a "Not about programming" close reason and can't find it.  Questions asking for career advice come up pretty often and I'm never entirely sure what to close them as. Do I use a custom reason, flag them as VLQ, leave a snarky comment to show everybody how clever I am?  I think there should be a general purpose "Off topic" close reason for exactly the cases you describe.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yeah, that's part of the problem. SO gets a *lot* of crap/blatantly offtopic questions. Am I supposed to custom close vote each question? We're unwilling/unadvised to give a comment for a downvote, but expected to put ourselves out there with a custom close reason, complete with auto-generated comment? Moderation seems like a mine-field unless you don't care.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: "*SO gets a lot of crap/blatantly offtopic questions.*" Maybe we circulate in different tags, but the number of questions that aren't genuinely about programming of some sort that I see is fairly small. The example you gave is a pretty clear "asking for off-site resource" kind of question. It's no different from asking for the documentation site for some API. My point is that there aren't that many non-programming questions that get asked where typing in a custom close reason is an onerous burden.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Flagging as VLQ is definitely the wrong choice. A VLQ flag just puts the question in the Triage queue, which forces multiple other people to make the choice between "Unsalvageable" (i.e. flag/vote to close) or "Requires Editing" (which goes to the Help & Improvement queue to be edited).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Comment: @gnat Seems related, although I'm not talking about using queues.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The off-site resource close reason is not just for subjective questions.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I don't have enough rep to vote to close but in the flagging menu I've used there is a flag reason for "Not about programming." It's just a little buried. *Flagging -> Close -> Off-Topic -> 
Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)*

Comment: I voted to close this question as "too broad".

Comment: @MarkBalhoff Apparently the "Blatantly off-topic" reason doesn't exist for close voting; there's a feature-request to get it back: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375077/can-we-have-a-off-topic-because-not-about-programming-close-reason-please

Comment: Skip it and leave close votes to people willing/able to put the time in. Don't worry, you are not the only user voting to close questions. Bad questions are being closed all the times, and quite fast. Sometimes, even if they are easily salvageable with minor edits.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Sounds like a case of someone misinterpreting the conversational use of the word "skip" as a reference to the Skip button in the review queues.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Thank you for taking notice of how you are choosing close reasons, asking on meta for feedback and showing interest in doing things better.

Yes, please use a different or even custom close reason where appropriate. That's why you're given multiple choices. Do not use "too broad" for questions that aren't programming-related. "Too broad" implies that the question would become answerable and on-topic once its scope is narrowed down. This requires the original question to be fundamentally programming-related in the first place, otherwise you can make it the best Stack Exchange question in the world, but it would still not be programming-related. (I don't recommend using close reasons on-site for the purpose of coaxing an off-topic question into something that is then eligible to be migrated to a different site...)

If a question is asking for contact information, "request for off-site resource" is probably appropriate, but if you have time you can emphasize the not-programming-related aspect of the question by saying "Asking for contact information is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it's not programming-related."

> For cases where I'm unwilling/unable (I'm getting off a bus, etc) to enter in a custom close reason, what's better?

Get off the bus. *Then* moderate the question.

You aren't going to lose access to the question just because you took a few extra seconds or minutes to finish whatever you were doing, away from your device. If you're using the mobile app, hopefully it hasn't crashed by the time you get back to it, and if you're using a web browser, keep the tab open, or use your browser history to return to the question and moderate it once you are able. If other users have moderated the question by the time you get back to it... the system works. Well, provided they moderated it correctly anyway.

Comment: This answer is super friendly and inclusive. And correct on the substance. Wow, it's possible to do both!?

Comment: "If you're using the mobile app" Since when is that a thing that is actually helpfull?

Comment: @Luuklag: The notifications are the only thing it's good for anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "Get off the bus"?

Comment: @anatolyg: Carcigenicate cited getting off the bus as an example of being too busy to close a question right away. So I'm telling them to focus on the task at hand and not worry about the question until it's done.

Comment: @anatolyg It wasn't an analogy. It was meant literally. As in "exiting a public transportation vehicle". See the OP.

Comment: @BoltClock Unfortunately, "You aren't going to lose access to the question just because you took a few extra seconds or minutes to finish whatever you were doing" isn't necessarily true when using the Android app. Say I see a question in need of some action. I need to ensure that I don't sleep my phone, or accidentally press the home button or else the app full on freezes, requiring me to restart the app, and find the question again. Even rotating my phone while viewing a question prevents the comment dialog from working, requiring to go out and back in. I'd rather deal with stuff as I see it

Comment: @BoltClock The take away I'm getting from this is "if you're going to vote, it should be for proper reasons". I'll just keep that in mind going forwards.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Yeah, I can't imagine the Android app being the most reliable in the world. Yes, that's the main thing you should take away, though if I may, I'd also like you to take away that you shouldn't feel responsible for moderating every question you see. This site is not your sole responsibility. It is not mine. Even I as a diamond mod am comfortable not prioritizing moderation over other tasks, but if making sure a question is closed is worth missing your stop or being late to work, then your efforts are very much appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't there a "Not about programming" close reason?

Comment: @chiliNUT: I've seen way too many people misidentifying programming questions as not programming related in proportion to blatantly non-programming questions for that to merit a canned option.

Comment: @chiliNUT: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375077/can-we-have-a-off-topic-because-not-about-programming-close-reason-please/375085#375085

Answer (score 19):

Don't close as too broad if it isn't too broad.

Instead, if and when it fits the bill, close as off-topic with

### Your own quick-to-type, generic off-topic close reason

I often end up typing "because it's about not programming" as custom off-topic reason. Because sometimes, there really isn't much more to say without sounding patronizing and/or ridiculous.

I mean, I could in principle expand on my reasoning:

> "[because...] asking for contact information does not constitute programming, unless you are using an API to do so, and if so provide a MCVE. Programming is when you write lines of code in a programming language or use technology to develop software powered by an automated machine, whereas this contact information lookup request appears to be manual."

or something like that. Okay, that's more complete, but is it worth the keystrokes? Is it more useful? No, it's *less useful* because silly fluff & clutter. Is it more polite? No, it's patronizing. At least that's kinda how I would receive it myself.

Instead, I effectively act as though there were a generic "off-topic" button by mechanically pasting in "not about programming", because that's what provides the clearest information in the most concise way.

Which leads me to a thing I'd really like because it would save me those repetitive keystrokes:

**I would like a generic "not about programming" off-topic radio button**

Comment: I thought "blatantly off-topic" was the category for "not about programming".

Comment: @RolandWeber, that is a flag, not a close reason.

Comment: Perhaps make a feature request out of this?, Although it isn't verry welcoming. But should we be in this case, as we aren't the right place for them, so we want to scare them away with peck and feathers, not real them in like a trojan horse

Comment: @RolandWeber ... and "blatantly off-topic" is a less helpful message to the OP than "not about programming" or something similarly explicit and descriptive.

Answer (score 16):

Stack Overflow is a programming site, and most people who come here know that. As such, the vast majority of questions not about programming we get are things about some aspect of computer technology. That's why we have specific close reasons for "general computing" and "server/network stuff", since we get a lot of those questions.

So in the majority of cases, we have a close reason to handle such issues. The cases you bring up are outliers. And in these cases, we have a generic "off-topic" reason, but you have to explain why it's off-topic.

A generic "off-topic" with no description has two basic problems. First, it is utterly useless to the person who asked the question. They don't get any information about what they did wrong, merely that it's "off-topic", whatever that means. With a description, even if they can't fix their question, they at least know something more about the topicality of the site.

Second, this also means that nobody else can decide if that reason is valid or not. Topicality is not a binary "yes/no" thing; there are corner cases which can be argued. And indeed, there are cases where someone might not realize that the question isn't on topic for some particular reason until they have it spelled out for them.

The ability to inspect the user's reasoning is very important: it also prevents *misuse* of the close reason. If you have no explanation for why a post is off-topic, or if your explanation is invalid, others can see that and choose not to close it for that reason. Whereas if there is no paper-trail, if it's just a generic "this post is off-topic... because" thing, then people can use it for whatever they want.

So to cause the least harm, use the proper close reason. Whether that's "off-topic due to asking for a resource" (like your example) or "off-topic due to ", just insert a (valid) reason. And if it's hard to come up with a reason... maybe the question isn't actually off-topic.

Remember: the last time users were abusing a close reason, we lost "too localized". Let's not make that mistake again, especially with "too broad".

Comment: The one who asks on SO for a contact information is not asking for an *off-site* (that is the wording in the close dialog) resource when he doesn't expect a link to the contact information, but rather an answer containing the information itself, at which point it is no longer *off-site* - otherwise every question to which the answer is obtained from elsewhere published knowledge would be off topic.

Comment: @Armali: Contact information is one of those things that's implied to be an off-site resource due to its nature.

Comment: @BoltClock - There exists no logical implication of the kind you stated - the _nature_ of information does not determine whether it is _off-site_ -, and I don't consider it helpful to ignore the inconsistencies in wording and intent of SO dialog texts.

Comment: @Armali: That sounds like using semantics against the clear spirit of the rule. Asking for contact information is *functionally* no different from asking for a link to an API's documentation. In both cases, you're not asking for information; you're asking for the *means* to get you information.