# Unsalvageable flag missing in triage

Tags: support, triage

Regarding this triage question https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26652582

My answer is "unsalvageable" because this is not a question about programming and thus it doesn't belong to SO, and might be redirected to another site of the SE network.

> **Unsalvageable** for questions that cannot or should not be answered and
> must therefore be removed from the site

However I dont find this option in the flags presented to me, and at that point I am blocked because none of the flags are meaningful for my "unsalvageable" answer....unless I am completely missing the point and should not have answered "unsalvagable" in the first place

[image: unsalvageable flags]

Comment: see also: [Can we have a “off-topic because not about programming” close reason please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375077/839601)

Comment: Clicking "Unsalvageable" is the same as clicking the flag dialog. So you'll need to click "needs improvement", then "A community-specific reason", then "Blatantly off-topic"/some custom message, if I understand your question correctly. But I'm a bit confused about what your question here is.

Comment: I've never liked the "unsalvageable" wording in triage. It isn't quite as bad as "requires editing" but it still causes a fair amount of confusion when it really just means "should be closed."